# Asp.net label returns empty string when using jQuery

Tags: 2010, jquery, asp.net, visual-web-part

I have created a SharePoint 2010 visual web part. In the page load event of the user control, i am setting the value of an asp.net label.

```
<asp:Label ID ="lbMessageIndex" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
           lbMessageIndex.Text = "0";                
        }
```

I also have a anchor tag with a click event `getLabelValues()` . In this method, when access the label value using jQuery, empty string value is returned.

```
function getLabelValues() {
        var index = $('#<%=lbMessageIndex.ClientID%>').text();
        alert(index);
    }
```

Note - `.html()` and `.val()` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the visibility. Control was not rendered when visibility was set to false. The fix is hide it using css. `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the Label property **Visibility="false"**. Instead use it as:

```
<asp:Label ID ="lbMessageIndex" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:Label>
```

then you can use:

```
    $('[id$="lbMessageIndex"]').html();
              OR
    $('[id*="lbMessageIndex"]').html();
```

To get the label value.